# Relative Paths not working on apache2 web server

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I'm pretty new to Linux and Apache and I have a problem with relative paths. I developed my website locally on a Mac, using relative paths and everything worked fine. My files are in a folder with following subfolders:

> - sites
> - css
> - images

Now I'm trying to set up my website on a Linux server running Debian. Almost everything worked out perfectly and I can reach my index.html through the internet. But obviously, relative paths are not working, since I placed my images, my css-file and my other sites in above subfolders, which I try to access with relative paths, but actually they are not working. When I try to access another site (about.html) which is in the sites-folder, I just get this error:

> 404 Not Found The requested URL /sites/about.html was not found on
>   this server.

For example, from my index.html, I'm trying to access my css-file with this path:

```
../css/standard.css
```

I've also implemented external paths, these are working correctly. I'd really appreciate any help or clues. Thank you very much!

Comment: What's the error recorded in Apache's error log? I'm not sure that Debian enables the error log by default (I would think it should, but the Linux distros do crazy crap); it should be in /var/log/httpd-error.log or something similar (again, various distros do crazy stuff and I can't memorize them all).

Comment: Thanks to the error-log, I found my mistake: I set one of my subdirectories (sites) as the DocumentRoot, with my index.html placed within this directory. Therefore, apache tried to access my css-file for example through this link: web/sites/css, but it should actually be web/css. Now I just put my index.html into the web-directory (which contains my subdirectories) and link from there to the other directories. Anyway, even though I'm satisfied with this solution, isn't there a way that I could leave the index.html in sites, without changing the DocumentRoot?
@Chris S: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons paths like `../somepath` are generally not allowed when the span outside the document route.  For a URL like `http:/www/example.com/content/index.html` they should be acceptable; but for a URL like `http://www.example.com/index.html` they should not.

I get requests for paths like `../../../../../etc/passwd`.  If this was honored, the requester would have a list of valid user ids on my system that they could try to crack.

As already noted, the error log is a good place to look for problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

for security its not allowable
for this u can use  directive 
add this to configuration file 

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
 
for more refer :http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory